# Why vertex removing request doesn't remove linked edge with AQL in Arangodb?

Tags: database, arangodb, aql

I have two document collections and one edge collection. Also I have a graph by this collections.

1. Can I remove vertex from graph with AQL query in Arangodb?
2. How can I remove vertex in graph so that edge will be deleted too? I need to do this with AQL query in Arangodb.

If I remove vertex in graphical interface then linked edges is removed too. 
Why Arangodb doesn't support removing vertices together with their linked edges?

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:

I have received the answer here:

[When graph consistency will be implemented in ArangoDB java driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594221/when-graph-consistency-will-be-implemented-in-arangodb-java-driver/52627509#52627509)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting vertices with associated edges is currently not handled via AQL.
However it is possible to design a query that does it.

A guide on how to delete a vertex with its linked edges via AQL has recently been created in the ArangoDB [documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/AQL/Examples/RemoveVertex.html) in the "Usual Query Patterns" section.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! Associated edges are deleted with a constructed query.

Comment: it seems this is new link https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/examples-remove-vertex.html