# When graph consistency will be implemented in ArangoDB java driver?

Tags: java, database, arangodb, aql

Some time ago I asked  about  [deleting vertices with associated edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650374/why-vertex-removing-request-doesnt-remove-linked-edge-with-aql-in-arangodb). The answer was that the edges don't deleted automatically by AQL when vertices are deleted.

I use Arango java driver for working with ArangoDB.

My questions are:

1. When graph consistency will be implemented  in ArangoDB java driver and edges will be deleted automatically by AQL when vertices are deleted?
2. Is it planned?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received the answer directly from ArangoDB contributors and they said that in v 3.4 the removing vertex through the graph leads to automatically remove the associated edges.

> To automatically delete an edge when a vertex gets deleted, you have
> to use:

> - named graphs

> AND

> - the graphAPI in the java driver https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/latest/com/arangodb/ArangoGraph.html

Answer (score 0):

Arango ensures consistency for named graphs. Here is the documentation that describes named graphs and the difference with unnamed (anonymous) graphs.
You can create named graphs directly in the graph section of the Arango gui

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/graphs/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I need consistency in work with AQL queries, because I use Arango driver. And in this case it doesn't work. I have checked and as I said  the edges don't deleted automatically by AQL when vertices are deleted. In the result there are edges which points to nowhere. The documentation confirms this: https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/AQL/Examples/RemoveVertex.html

Comment: Humn...interesting. the documentation seems to contradict itself. Which driver are you using? The javascript driver seems to support consistency when deleting vertices: https://docs.arangodb.com/devel/Manual/Graphs/GeneralGraphs/Management.html#remove-a-vertex. "graph.vertexCollectionName.remove" [...] "removes all ingoing and outgoing edges of the vertex recursively"

Comment: I use java driver and send AQL queries through it to delete vertex. Actually it is the same as send an AQL query via ArangoDB web interface on the tab "Queries". And the result is the same. I think maybe somebody knows when it will be implement.